# Unable to install dapper 2.0.30 with .net framework 4.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orm, dapper, .net-framework-version

I am learning dapper ORM. While installing it through nuget package manager I am getting following error:

> Could not install package 'Dapper 2.0.30'. You are trying to install
>   this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5',
>   but the package does not contain any assembly references or content
>   files that are compatible with that framework. For more information,
>   contact the package author.

In target framework option in project properties I've changed .net framework from 2.0 to 4.5.1

Answer (score 3):

No 2.* (or above) version of Dapper supports .NET 4.5.*, and there are no plans to do so. You will have to update your target framework, or stick with older versions of the tool. Preferably the first.

Ultimately [you should expect this to be more and more of a problem](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2020/01/net-core-net-5-exodus-of-net-framework.html) if you choose to use old frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I saw:

- **Dapper 1.60.1** needs **.NET 4.5.1**
- **Dapper 1.50.4** needs **.NET 4.5.1**
- **Dapper 1.50.2** needs **.NET 4.0**

Therefore, having **.NET 4.5**, I installed **Dapper 1.50.2**

Answer (score 0):

`dapper 2.0.30` of  supports only `.NET Framework 4.6.1` and `.NET Standard 2.0`

the max version that supports `.NET Framework 4.5` is `dapper 1.50.2`

More informations can be found on the official nuget link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/1.50.2#dependencies-tab